# size allocation in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Generally in simulink, the sizes need to be pre-allocated when writing 'Matlab fcn'. Within the function this can be declared by using

```
coder.varsize('var',[n, m]);
```

where *n* and *m* give the maximum possible size. The issue I am having is with the following function:

```
function y = fcn(u)
    coder.varsize('tmp',[1, 100])
    test = ((abs(diff(u)))*100 > 10);
    i1 = find(test,1,'first');
    i2 = find(test,1,'last');
    while i2>=i1
        i1 = max(1,i1-1);
        i2 = i2+1;
        tmp = u(i1:i2);
        t1 = conv(tmp,[1 2 1]/4);
        t2 = t1(2:end-1);
        t2(1) = t2(1)+t1(1);
        t2(end) = t2(end)+t1(end);
        u(i1:i2) = t2;
        test = ((abs(diff(u)))*100 > 10);
        i1 = find(test,1,'first');
        i2 = find(test,1,'last');
    end
    y = u;
end
```

Since the size of *tmp* depends upon what the values of *i1* and *i2* are. Generally the declaration with *coder.varsize* should not be a problem, but this time I do not know how to implement this.

Let me know if you need more information!

Edit: If I fix the output sizes of the function, I get

```
Errors occurred during parsing of MATLAB function 'MATLAB Function'
```

If I set the output sizes of the function as 'inherited', I get

```
Error in default port dimensions function of S-function 'MATLAB Function'. This function does not fully set the dimensions of output port 3
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: yeah...it cannot decide the sizes of the variables. Mind you that if I remove the part related to *tmpProfile(i1:i2)*, there is no longer any error!

Comment: Show us the _exact_ error message, _not_ your interpretation of it.

Comment: @PhilGoddard Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there are a couple of things going on.

Firstly, the code generator doesn't know that the optional inputs you are using with `find` leads to a scalar output.  (And in fact it doesn't in that the output may be empty, or scalar.)  To overcome this use `find` without any optional inputs and then extract the first and last element when defining `i1` and `i2`.

Secondly, you need to correctly handle the cases where `find` does return an empty output.  I have done this in the example code below, but you almost certainly need to modify it to suit the specific logic you need in your actual model.

```
function y = fcn(u)

coder.varsize('tmp',[1, 100]);
coder.varsize('find_idx',[1, 100]);

test = ((abs(diff(u)))*100 > 10);
find_idx = find(test);
if ~isempty(find_idx)
    i1 = find_idx(1); % find(test,1,'first');
    i2 = find_idx(end); %find(test,1,'last');

    while i2>=i1
        i1 = max(1,i1-1);
        i2 = i2+1;
        tmp = u(i1:i2);
        t1 = conv(tmp,[1 2 1]/4);
        t2 = t1(2:end-1);
        t2(1) = t2(1)+t1(1);
        t2(end) = t2(end)+t1(end);
        u(i1:i2) = t2;
        test = ((abs(diff(u)))*100 > 10);
        find_idx = find(test);
        if ~isempty(find_idx)
            i1 = find_idx(1); % find(test,1,'first');
            i2 = find_idx(end); %find(test,1,'last');
        else
            break
        end
    end
    y = u;
else
    y = u;
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man...been wrecking my brain with this. I do want to know how you figured it out. In my case I knew the need to declare variable size array through *coder.varsize* with only the requirement of upper bound to be mentioned with regards to its size. It should mean that empty arrays should be permissible for assignment. In any case, the error warnings did not give any clues. I have used *coder.varsize* a lot and have never come across this issue before. Unless you had the intuition/understanding to scrutinize the empty arrays being an issue, what helped you to figure it out?